# Definite integral over product of two bessel function with different argument

Tags: definite-integrals, bessel-functions

What is the solution of the integral: $\int_0^a J_s(k_1 \rho)J_{s+1} (k_2 \rho ) \rho~ d\rho $ where the integer $s \ge 0 $

Comment: Are you sure that's supposed to be $s+1$ and not $s$ ? I think you should refer to the [orthogonality of Bessel functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/204297/orthogonality-of-bessel-functions).

Comment: Yeah, I'd like to know know solution about difference order. 
Especially when the difference is 1.

Comment: In that case, I'd try using the recurrence relations for Bessel functions and then invoke orthogonality.